# Difference between Visual Studio 2015 include paths and INCLUDE environment variable

Tags: c++, visual-studio, preprocessor, include-path

In order to preprocess a Visual Studio 2015 C/C++ file programmatically I deduce the Visual Studio include paths from the INCLUDE environment variable after opening the Visual Studio 2015 Developer Command Prompt.

In my case this is:

`INCLUDE=C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\ATLMFC\INCLUDE;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\ucrt;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\NETFXSDK\4.6.1\include\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\shared;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\um;C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.17763.0\winrt;`

This works fine except for an important detail. If I open Visual Studio 2015 and I right click a VCX project file and I select Properties/Configuration Properties/VC++ Directories/Include Directories and I click Edit/Macros >>/$(IncludePath) I get the same directories but for another version of Windows Kits, i.e. 10.0.10240.0. As a consequence my preprocessed file is different if compared to the file that is preprocessed by Visual Studio itself.

My question is how do I get the real IncludePath from Visual Studio for this Windows Kits version? Apparently the INCLUDE environment variable is not completely right.